# dc.js linechart - make lines crOss instead of stacking on top of eachother

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have a dc line chart that has a date Dimension and is linked to several other columns from my data.
The chart values linked to the date are percentages but currently they stack, and the Y axis  ends up being over 1000 when it should be a max of 100 and the lines should cross over and represent a percentage.
Because  I am grouping by date it adds the total percent for that date, which could in theory be 300 for 3 rows of data, is there a way to make this be a max of 100, perhaps averaging the value and not have the lines stack but cross over each other ?

```
    var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Date;});
    var a=dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.a;});
    hitslineChart
    .width(1000).height(300)
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(a,"a")
    .stack(b,"b")
    .stack(c,"c")
    .stack(d,"d") 
    .stack(e,"e")    
    .stack(f,"f")    
    .renderArea(false)//fills in the areas
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
    .brushOn(true)

    .legend(dc.legend().x(50).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .yAxisLabel("Score");
```

Comment: Renaming tag - `dc` is a venerable **desk calculator** from the 70's - `dc.js` is the javascript **dimensional charting** library.